# AWS Lambda will not return query

Tags: c#, json, amazon-web-services, .net-core, aws-lambda

I have a lambda built with ApiGateway / Serverless.

It will execute a MySQL query. The MySQL Server is up and running and performing other queries with no issues, it seems that this is the only Lambda that returns an empty object.

It accepts a post request with a ID number in the body and then queries the DB and returns the object/data. Like before the server is running correctly. Just this returns and empty object.

I started to think that this maybe completing before the results were returned, I tried running this both sync and aync with the same results.

I am newish to c# so forgive if the code could be more efficient.

No clue as to why this returns a empty object everytime.

```
namespace Aws.Lambda
{
    public class SearchHandler:BaseHandler
    {
        public async Task<APIGatewayProxyResponse> getId(LambdaRequest request)
        {
            var error = new Errorhandle();
            var connect = new Connection(); //THIS IS THE DATABASE CONNECTION CLASS (WORKS)

            var result = new List<ReturnTypes>();
            var number = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<bodyType>(request.body);
            bool boolNumber = String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(number.factura);

            try
            {
                if(boolNumber)
                {
                    return error.errorApiResponse("empty");
                }
                else
                {
                   await Task.Yield(); // TRYING TO ASYNC / AWAIT THIS, 
     
                   string x = $"SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE ID_NUM ='{number}'";
                   Console.WriteLine(x); //LOGGING THE QUERY FOR ERRORS (NONE FOUND COPY AND PASTED QUERY AND IT WORKED IN WORKBENCH).

                   var results = connect.getData(x); //QUERY EXECUTE PASS TO FUNCTION MADE IN CLASS

                   if(!results.Read())
                   {
                       return error.errorApiResponse("reader is empty");
                   }
                     while (results.Read())
                    {
                        resultList.Add(insertData(results));
                    }
                    return new APIGatewayProxyResponse
                    {
                        StatusCode = 200,
                        Body = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(resultList),
                        Headers = headerList = new Dictionary<string, string>
                { 
                  { "Content-Type", "application/json" }, 
                  { "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*" },
                  {"Access-Control-Allow-Methods","OPTIONS,GET"}
                };
                    };
                }
            } catch (Exception e)
            {
                return error.errorApiResponse("exception error");
                throw e; 
            }
        }


        private static ReturnTypes insertData(System.Data.IDataReader results)
        {
            return new ReturnTypes { Num = results["ID"], Body = results["UUID"];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and capture the response.  The response may give more details why you are not getting a null response.

Comment: Are you sure that in your query  `ID_NUM='{number}'` will yield a result as it is comparing the string representation of the number?

Comment: @MohsinMehmood I am passing number to a string thats why I have quotes. When lambda logs the query I copy and paste it in mysql workbench with no issues.

Comment: You can try without quotes like `string x = $"SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE ID_NUM ={number}";`

Comment: @MohsinMehmood I have, no success. Is it possible this function is completing before the query is returning results fully? Even if its running sync. Im coming from a typescript background so sometimes you can get away with rely on synchronism. Wondering if its the same with c#